# Differences in using between *array2[0] and **arrays

Tags: c

I'm trying to understand the difference between pointers and arrays so I've created a simple program. All I'm doing is assigning a character to pointer pointing to a char. So as I know there is two methods for doing that.
First one: by using the derefrence operator
Second one: by using squares bracket

For more details let me provide the code

```
char **array2 = malloc(sizeof(char*));
*array2[0] = 'c';
```

The above seems not working

And the second version I've tried is this

```
char **array2 = malloc(sizeof(char*));
**array2 = 'c';
```

First, non of theses codes are working for me.
Second, what are the differences between these two versions

Comment: Both of these invoke *undefined behavior*. I'm not entirely clear why you're interested in knowing the "differences" of two code sets that *don't work*.

Comment: But if I wanna assign a character to my variable how could I go about doing that? Thanks, but what is wrong ?

Comment: Your variable is a pointer-to-pointer-to-char. You don't assign a character to it. You assign an *address* to it (and you did; the result of a `malloc` region of memory large enough to hold *one* pointer, so far so good). The problem is, *that* pointer, the one at dereferenced `*array2`, doesn't address anything. It is indeterminate. You either need another `malloc`, an otherwise preexisting location where a `char` can be stored and addressed, or, the most likely of all of these, to *not* use double-indirection in the first place.

Comment: Stack Overflow should not be used to learn just by asking arbitrary questions. To learn C, read a good primer or textbook and work through its exercises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntactically, `x[y]` and `*(x + y)` are exactly the same.  So both pieces of code are doing the same thing.  The problem is that you're trying to dereference an invalid pointer.

After the initialization, `array2` pointer to a single object of type `char *` which can be accessed as either `array2[0]` or `*array`.  This pointer object is uninitialized.  You then attempt to dereference this uninitialized pointer and assign a value to the dereferenced objects.  Attempting to dereference an invalid pointer triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You can fix this by either allocating memory for this pointer to point to:

```
char **array2 = malloc(sizeof(char*));
array2[0] = malloc(sizeof(char));
*array2[0] = 'c';
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
char **array2 = malloc(sizeof(char*));
*array2 = malloc(sizeof(char));
**array2 = 'c';
```

Or you get get rid of the extra level of indirection:

```
char *array2 = malloc(sizeof(char));
array2[0] = 'c';
*array2 = 'c';
```